# CSS - Align Div Elements

Tags: javascript, css, html

I am trying to align my DIV elements such that my headings are equally spaced from their corresponding values.

Currently my output looks like this: [image]

My Javascript is as follows:

```
                wrapper.appendTo('body')
                dealTitleDiv.appendTo('#wrapper');
                dealTitleValueDiv.appendTo('#wrapper');

                wrapperOne.appendTo('body')
                dealNameDiv.appendTo('#wrapperOne');
                dealNameValueDiv.appendTo('#wrapperOne');

                wrapperTwo.appendTo('body')
                addressDiv.appendTo('#wrapperTwo');
                addressValueDiv.appendTo('#wrapperTwo');

                wrapperThree.appendTo('body')
                disclaimerDiv.appendTo('#wrapperThree');
                disclaimerValueDiv.appendTo('#wrapperThree');
```

My CSS:

```
body
{
background-color:#5CD65C;
}


#wrapper
{
    width:300px;
}
#dealTitleDiv
{
    width:100px;
    float: left;      
}

#dealTitleValueDiv
{
    width:215px;
    float: right;   
}

#wrapperOne
{
    width:320px;
}
#dealNameDiv
{
    width:100px;
    float: left;
    clear: left;
}

#dealNameValueDiv
{
    width:215px;
    float: right;   
}

#wrapperTwo
{
    width:320px;
}
#addressDiv
{
    width:100px;
    float: left;
    clear: left;
}

#addressValueDiv
{
     width:215px;
    float: right; 
}


#wrapperThree
{
    width:320px;
}

#disclaimerDiv
{
    width:100px;
    float: left;
    clear:left;
}

#disclaimerValueDiv
{
    width:215px;
    float: right; 
}
```

HTML (doesn't contain much, so I just pasted the body)

```
<body>
<div id='loadingDiv2'>
            Please wait...Retrieving Deals  <img src="https://i.stack.imgur.com/FhHRx.gif" />
</div> 


</body>
```

I can't seem to work out a few things:
1) Why "$8 Oyster Special" is not aligned with the values below it.

2) Why "Fish" is appearing under "Name"

3) How to keep the text in "Disclaimer" on the screen.

This is being run on my Samsung Galaxy S2 mobile.

If someone could help me resolve a few of these issues, I'd greatly appreciate it!

Comment: css,jquery is ok where html is ?

Comment: Hi Samitha, I have edited my question to include the HTML. The HTML is quite empty though...

Comment: Where is your html code which contain above screen shot ?  http://jsfiddle.net/SNGQb/

Comment: I basically only show the loading image when when I am loading something and then I hide it... It is in my Javascript code, which I didn't copy here.

Comment: So,what do you need to archive now ?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

It looks like you are trying to build a table of data.  For actual data tables, there's nothing wrong with using `<table>`:

```
<table id="wrapper">
    <tr>
        <td>Deal Title</td>
        <td>$8 Special</td>
    </tr>
    <tr>
        <td>Name</td>
        <td>Fish</td>
    </tr>
</table>
```

Then the only CSS you need is

```
#wrapper {
    width:300px;
}
```

(See [jsfiddle](http://jsfiddle.net/7BYTD/) to experiment.)

Comment: Thanks cxw. This looks simpler. I'll give it a try and let you know.

Answer (score 1):

for each "row" that you want to add, add elements of those supposed "row" within a div, which will let you align the text elements.

```
<div id="wrapper">
    <div class="row">
        <div id="dealTitle">Some text</div>
        <div id="dealTitleValueDiv">Some value text</div>
    </div>
    <div class="row">
        ...
        ...
    </div>
</div>
```

so you'd want the end HTML to be like this.