# Align first content center and second content extreme right in div

Tags: html, css, twitter-bootstrap-3

I have to align two contents in div as per below screenshot. I do not want to use flex as I am completely new to it. I have bootstrap3 library in my project

1. first content exactly at center
2. second content should be at extreme right. very minimum space at right corner will be ok.

I checked, `float:right` but it is not aligning second content at extreme right. how to fix?

[image]

Comment: can you please give your code snippet to solve your problem

Comment: Does this answer your question? [CSS - Align Div Elements](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/19663287/css-align-div-elements)

Answer (score 2):

Use `display: flex` and add invisible element. Then use `justify-content: space-between;` to align the items one on the left, one center and one on the right.
If you need vertical center use `align-items: center;`

Learn more on flex [here](https://www.w3schools.com/css/css3_flexbox_container.asp). The [bootstrap documentation](https://getbootstrap.com/docs/5.0/utilities/flex/#wrap) does great job visualizing more configurations.

```css
.parent {
  display: flex;
  justify-content: space-between;
  align-items: center;
  border: 1px solid black;
  width: 200px;
  height: 40px;
}

.left-child {
  visibility: hidden;
}

.center-child {
  background: red;
  width: 10px;
  height: 20px;
}

.right-child {
  background: red;
  width: 10px;
  height: 20px;
}
```

```html
<div class="parent">
  <div class="left-child"></div>
  <div class="center-child"></div>
  <div class="right-child"></div>
</div>
```

Comment: **I did not up-vote the question for following reasons:** The questions is specifically labled as `twitter-bootstrap-3`. As such the answer should contain a solution with the use of bootstrap instead of overwriting that library. However I believe that a down-vote in this case might be to harsh.

Comment: I do not know basic of flex. is it possible to do using bootstrap?

Comment: @SSD It can be done with bootstrap 4+, as version 3 does not include the Flex classes.

Answer (score 0):

In my answer, you have to change the margin-top of the right content as the font-size or height of the center content

```
<style type="text/css">
.center{
    text-align:center;
    margin:auto;
    display:block;
}
.right{
    float:right;
    margin-top:-18px;
}
</style>
<span class="center">Center</span>

<span class="right">Right</span>
```

Comment: **I did not up-vote the question for following reasons:** The questions is specifically labled as `twitter-bootstrap-3`. As such the answer should contain a solution with the use of bootstrap instead of overwriting that library. However I believe that a down-vote in this case might be to harsh.

Comment: any specific reason to add margin-top:-18 px.